# SOLR Search. Search for additional documents after initial match

Tags: solr

I have the following problem to solve. 
Client sends the id of the document. This is an HTTP Get to a proxy (not directly to SOLR). Example:
baseURL/movies/{id}

The response of this call will be a list of variants of this movie. 
In order to find the variants I want to perform a SOLR search using title and some other fields, e.g.

/movies/select?q=title:spiderman+year:2001

it will expect the different variants of Spiderman e.g. SpiderMan, Spiderman HD. etc
The problem I have now is that the proxy service will not have the title of the original movie. It will get only the id of this movie for the API.

My approach so far is to get the original movie information using the id,
e.g. 
/movies/select?id={id}

After I get the original movie then I perform a second request to SOLR search for the variants.

Any ideas how to avoid the two calls to SOLR search?

Comment: could you add an example? so far it's not 100% clear how your docs is organized and how users search for movies. pls add it into question, not in comment

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added some examples!